# Oracle - SQL to concatenate multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Let’ say I have a table with 3 columns

```
   ID INTEGER,
   OFFSET INTEGER,
   STR VARCHAR(50)
```

Containing values:

```
ID          OFFSET   STR
1              1              TestSTR1
1              2              TestSTR3
1              3              TestSTR5
2              1              TestSTR4
2              2              TestSTR2
3              1              TestSTR6
```

I would like to pull the concatenated “STR” for each ID (ordered by OFFSET). So basically, what I want is:

```
ID           STR
1              TestSTR1TestSTR3TestSTR5
2              TestSTR4TestSTR2
3              TestSTR6
```

Any thoughts on how would you construct a similar query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have Oracle 11g you could use the LISTAGG() function for this:

```
SELECT
      id
    , listagg(str) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OFFSET) AS str_of_str
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm
and [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b24a5/2)

```
  | ID |               STR_OF_STR |
    |----|--------------------------|
    |  1 | TestSTR1TestSTR3TestSTR5 |
    |  2 |         TestSTR4TestSTR2 |
    |  3 |                 TestSTR6 |
```

Answer (score 8):

in **`Oracle 11g`** you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
ID, 
LISTAGG(STR, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OFFSET) AS STR
FROM  Table
GROUP BY ID;
```

in `**Oracle 9i**` you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
ID,
rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement(e,STR||' ')).extract ('//text()'), ' ') AS STR
FROM  Table
GROUP BY ID;
```